# Using concat() with a separator in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to concatenate strings in month/date/year elements into a single value that displays MM/DD/YYYY, but I can't find a way to do it in xslt 1.0 that will include the '/' separator in the way a string-join function would in xslt 2.0. I need to do this without creating new templates or using variables/if-logic because we haven't "learned" that yet in my class. The section of code I'm trying to concatenate looks like this:

```
<publishedDate>
<month>7</month>
<day>9</day>
<year>2007</year>
</publishedDate>
```

Currently the best I can do is:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(
format-number(publishedDate/month, '##00', 'date'),
format-number(publishedDate/day, '##00', 'date'),
format-number(publishedDate/year, '####', 'date')
)"/>
```

Which outputs dates like this: 03082014

In the mean time, for the purposed of the assignment, I'm forced to use a hideous, lengthy workaround that looks like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(publishedDate/month, '##00', 'date')"/>/
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(publishedDate/day, '##00', 'date')" />/
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(publishedDate/year, '####', 'date')" />
```

And outputs correctly (i.e. 03/08/2014). Do you guys know a way to get this output by using a a 1.0 function? Thanks!

Comment: You're almost there. You just need to add '/' terms in the concat itself: `concat(format-number(...), '/', format-number(...), '/', format-number(...))`

Answer (score 5):

You're almost there. You just need to add extra parameters containing `'/'` in the `concat()` itself (it's still XSLT 1.0 - you can have more than three terms):

```
concat(format-number(...), '/', format-number(...), '/', format-number(...))
```

Answer (score 2):

XPath 2.0 (included in XSLT 2.0) would have support for a **general solution using `string-join($sequence, $seperator)`**:

```
string-join((
    format-number(publishedDate/month, '##00', 'date'),
    format-number(publishedDate/day, '##00', 'date'),
    format-number(publishedDate/year, '####', 'date')
  ), '/')
```

This is especially important for joining arbitrary-length sequences, which is not possible in XPath 1.0.

As you only want to combine a **fixed number of strings** (year/month/day), using `concat(...)` provided by XPath 1.0/XSLT 1.0 is totally fine:

```
concat(
  format-number(publishedDate/month, '##00', 'date'),
  '/',
  format-number(publishedDate/day, '##00', 'date'),
  '/',
  format-number(publishedDate/year, '####', 'date')
)
```